# containing an absolute element within a parent element

Tags: html, css

I am finding it strange that my absolute element is completely outside the parent element. I want it just perfectly contained within 100% of the element, nothing outside of it, but this doesn't seem to be how it happens. The absolute element left and top just start from the parent element, the absolute element is on 100% of the rest of the document.

HTML

```
<div id="box" class="home_box">
    <div class="box_hover"></div>
    <h3>Heading/h3>
    <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#box {height:200px; width:400px;}
.box_hover {background:#000; height:100%; opacity:0.1; position:absolute; width:100%;}
```

As you can see the height and width are 100%. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

`#box` needs to be `position: relative`, `position: fixed`, or `position: absolute` for a `position: absolute` child element to be positioned relative to it.

An `absolute`ly positioned element will be positioned to the closest parent whose position is set to `relative`, `absolute`, or `fixed`. Without such a parent, it'll be positioned relative to the body.

`position: relative` for `#box` is most likely what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `position:relative` to parent element